# Need to show custom css in TinyMCE editor in Wordpress admin section

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have customized wordpress blog, which works fine. The problem is that when i try to edit the posts/pages in admin section with Editor(TinyMCE), the view is completly different form the frontend. So i need to include the css file to this editor which i have used in front end.

Please anyone suggest me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a ready-to-use code, but I know what you need to do it yourself.

**First way:** Where TinyMCE is being initialized, see the theme and the skin. It is possible via "View source" in browser.

Then find TinyMCE's folder on your server and edit (or replace) there the file

`tinymce/themes/<theme name>/skins/<skin name>/content.css`

Course, you could add your own skin to keep the TinyMCE's original package. But it is a kind of a hard work.

**Another way:** There's a param of TinyMCE `init()` which helps to add an **extra** content css file (see in TinyMCE's wiki). So you'll need to edit WordPress TinyMCE initialization, and overload TinyMCE's old styles.